# Implementing Oauth on laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to convert this row query to laravel migration

```
CREATE TABLE oauth_clients 
(
    client_id VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, 
    client_secret VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, 
    redirect_uri VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL, 
    grant_types VARCHAR(80), 
    scope VARCHAR(100), 
    user_id VARCHAR(80), 
    CONSTRAINT client_id_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);
```

But I am confused about last two lines.

Comment: Can you show your migration code?

Comment: $table->string('client_id', 80)->nullable(false)->primary();
            $table->string('client_secret', 80)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('redirect_uri', 2000)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('grant_types', 80)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('scope', 100)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('user_id', 80)->nullable(false);
            $table
                ->foreign( 'client_id_pk' )
                ->references( 'client_id' )

Comment: Just for the record, when you install **Laravel Passport** with `composer require laravel/passport` (which is the Laravel official package for OAuth implementation), you can simply run `php artisan migrate` to create the *oauth_clients* and *oauth_access_tokens* migrations automatically. See *https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport* for further information.